# Nested viewFlipper Layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-layout, viewflipper

I am trying to create a custom tabbed layout with a viewflipper. Therefore, I need two buttons side-by-side at the top of the screen. I have this. However, I am trying to get the viewFlipper content below these two buttons. Here is my current XML (which does not show the textviews)

```
        <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout01" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="#FAFAFA"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout02" 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="button 1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0dip" layout_weight = ".5"/>
            <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:text="button 2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0dip" layout_weight = ".5"/>
    </LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout02">
    <ViewFlipper 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper01">

        <include 
            android:id="@+id/one" 
            layout="@layout/view_one" />
        <include 
            android:id="@+id/two" 
            layout="@layout/view_two" />

    </ViewFlipper>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `LinearLayout` that contains the buttons has a `layout_height="fill_parent"`. You need to set that to `wrap_content` and also specify the `orientation="vertical"` in the parent `LinearLayout`. You'll also need to specify a `layout_weight` for the view that you want to stretch to fill.

Because `linearLayout01` `LinearLayout` has its `layout_height` set to `fill_parent`, android is going to make it take up the reset of the screen. The content below that will not be visible at all because it is off the screen.

```
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout01" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout02" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:id="@+id/button01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button 1" android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/button02" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button 2" android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/relativeLayout01" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1">
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/flipper01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        />  
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text2"
        />  

    </ViewFlipper>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can see the a big white space where the buttons *should* be, and at the bottom is the textviews/view/etc. No buttons.

Comment: Updated. On your `RelativeLayout`, the `layout_height` needed to be `0dp` and the `layout_weight='1'`

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I edited my original post to have my current XML file - as it's changed a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout01" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:orientation="vertical" >   

            <Button android:id="@+id/button01" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Button 1" 
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/button02" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Button 2" 
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipper01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/relativeLayout01" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1">

        <!-- Screen 1: Wherever view you want to display on the first screen -->
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/relativeLayout02" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1">

        <!-- Screen 2: Wherever view you want to display on the second screen -->
    </RelativeLayout>

</ViewFlipper></LinearLayout>
```

Generally, you have to ViewFlipper that contains the two or more layout that you want to display when, for example, click a buttom and whatever you want to see in all of screen, write outside of ViewPager tag.