# Nested Layout Problem - View not appearing

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-layout

What I have is two buttons at the top (equally filling 50% of the width of the screen) and below I have a ViewFlipper. The flipper is not appearing anymore. :(

```
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="#FAFAFA"

        <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/linearLayout02" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <Button 
                        android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="button 1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0dp" 
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:text="button 2" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0dp" 
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout02">

            <ViewFlipper 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/viewFlipper01">

            <include android:id="@+id/one" layout="@layout/view_one" />
            <include android:id="@+id/two" layout="@layout/view_two" />

            </ViewFlipper>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Duplicate question. Similar answer was given as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333881/nested-viewflipper-layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add android:orientation="vertical" to first LinearLayout

Comment: Perfect. I had that earlier, but I took it off and it helped with something...guess I fixed both problems. :)

Answer (score 0):

try to set the buttons width to fill parent. that's the only thing that comes to my mind when i see your code. having them on fill parent with a same weight will also make them equaly wide.

And also Orientation Vertical