# How to properly inflate a layout with a nested ViewFlipper?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, viewflipper, findviewbyid

I used to have a simple main.xml layout that had only 2 views flipped via ViewFlipper wrapper. It worked (still works) great, using the following code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mTV1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview01);
mTV2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview02);
mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper01);
```

I now want to add 2 buttons on top of the original views, in a fashion similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6334526/1088880):

```
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout01" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout02" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:id="@+id/button01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button 1" android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/button02" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button 2" android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/relativeLayout01" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1">
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/flipper01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        />  
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text2"
        />  

    </ViewFlipper>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is I intuitively modified the original code to by inserting a findViewById for the composite layout:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mCompositeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout02);
mTV1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview01);
mTV2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview02);
mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper01);
```

But it displays exactly the same as before! As if I never added extra linearLayout02 containing the buttons.

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try project->clean (If you use Eclipse) and insure that you are editing right main.xml file. Your code works, neither CompositeLayout nor ViewFlipper matters, buttons are drawn.

If you're sure that nothing is missing and buttons still not drawn then try to add android:layout_weight into your new LinearLayout (containing buttons). (For my Galaxy Nexus everything is ok without weight but problem may appear because of android device fragmentation)

Comment: Thanks. I did `Project > Clean` countless times so that wasn't it. But... I just discovered that I mistakenly had `fill_parent` for the buttons instead of `wrap_content` in `android:layout_height`. So many hours lost due to a silly typo...